# Program to find whether a string is substring of another string

Tags: python, python-2.7

`str1` is a string in which the search is to be performed (the haystack). `str2` is the string to be found (the needle). `count` will count the number of occurences of `str2` in `str1`.

The code below gives me a syntax error in the last line. Please suggest changes.

```
str1 = raw_input()
str2 = raw_input()
count = 0
for i in range(0,len(str1)) :

    if ( str1.find(str2, i, i+len(str2))) : 
        count=count+1
print count
```

Comment: Use `str1.count(str2)`..

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, that won't count overlapping strings

Comment: @MarounMaroun, edited too!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't get it.. what do you mean by overlapping strings?

Comment: @MarounMaroun, the OP seems to be counting so they seem to want to find all occurrences so "bobob".count("bob") = 1 when it is 2 if you consider overlapping strings

Answer (score 4):

To find out if a string is a substring of another string, you can use the `in` operator

```
"abc" in "abcd" # will return true
```

And to count occurences you can use the `count` method of string

```
"abcda".count("a") # will return 2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count how many times str2 is in str1 including overlapping strings:

```
str1 = raw_input() # input() if using python3
str2 = raw_input() 
print(sum(str1[i:i+len(str2)] == str2 for i in xrange(len(str1)) ))
```

Example:

```
In [12]: paste
str1 = raw_input()
str2 = raw_input()
sum(str1[i:i+len(str2)] == str2 for i in xrange(len(str1)))

## -- End pasted text --
bobob
bob
Out[12]: 2
```

Comment: good answer, this covers overlapping strings too.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, i may be wrong but the OP's code does look like some attempt at doing the same.